# Error: 'CLSS' was not declared inside this scope?

Tags: c++

Why isn't my function 'CSS()' working in this code, the error is:

```
C:\Users\KEstudio\Desktop\Programming\Learning C++ resources\projects\homework     saver\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\KEstudio\Desktop\Programming\Learning C++ resources\projects\homework    saver\main.cpp|20|error: 'CLSS' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void ClSS()
{
    system("CLS");
}
const char* CTS(string);

int main()
{
    A:
    string HWS, HW;//We will be saving our input in this
    cout << "Please enter the homework subject:" << endl;
    getline(cin, HWS);
    CLSS();

    cout << "Please enter the homework:" << endl;
    getline(cin, HW);
    CLSS();

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(CTS(HWS+".txt"));
    myfile << HW;
    myfile.close();

    cout << "You have saved the information to a file! :D" << endl;

    string SEL;
    bool ASEL=false;
    cout << "Do you wan't to add another entry? yes or no" << endl;
    getline(cin, SEL);
    system("CLS");
    if(SEL=="yes" || SEL=="Yes" || SEL=="YES" || SEL=="Y" || SEL=="y")
        ASEL=true;
    else
        ASEL=false;
    if(ASEL==true)
        goto A;
    return 0;
}

const char* CTS(string strng)
{
    const char* FON;
    FON=strng.c_str();
    return FON;
}
```

I can see that my function IS declared, I'm aware that C++ wouldn't have bugs like this, so I AM doing something wrong, there is no way that this is a bug with C++, so please, tell me what i'm doing wrong (Hopefully it's not completely dumb so i don't look too stupid, although with a code like this, it probably will be a simply solution)
Sorry for rambling on here, stack overflow has made me type more detail.

Ok I can see that CLSS is declared above the main function, and functions don't need to be declared inside the main function for them to work inside it.

Comment: Note: your `CTS` function has **undefined behavior**, returning a pointer to the internal buffer of a local `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `ClSS()`, but you are calling `CLSS()`. The latter isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: Thankyou, I must have spent over 20 minutes looking for the error, almost going mad, and I knew it.. It was simple :P

Comment: @user2003618 Case-sensitive search can be quite useful.